# get the value of a c constant

Tags: c++, c

I have a .h file in which hundreds of constants are defined as macros:

```
#define C_CONST_NAME Value
```

What I need is a function that can dynamically get the value of one of these constants.

needed function header :

```
int getConstValue(char * constName);
```

Is that even possible in the C langage?

---- EDIT

Thanks for the help, That was  quick :)

as i was thinking there is no miracle solution for my needs.

In fact the header file i use is generated by "SCADE : http://www.esterel-technologies.com/products/scade-suite/"

On of the solution i got from @Chris is to use some python to generate c code that does the work.

Now its to me to make some optimizations in order to find the constant name. I have more than 5000 constants O(500^2)

i'm also looking at the "X-Macros" The first time i hear of that, home it works in C because i'm not allowed to use c++.

Thanks

Comment: The constants are pre-processor not compiler constants, you have to move into the object space, e.g. a [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: Not sure why you would need to do this, but its not possible dynamically. Your 'constants' as defined above do not actually exist past the compilation of your program source. They get substituted by the pre-processor with their actual values.

Comment: Don't use defined constants.  Use an associative array with const values.

Comment: Usually, such a thing is implemented similarly to this: [part 1](http://www.google.com/codesearch#Wag-gKnV1r8/Alc/ALc.c&q=openal-soft&l=281) ,  [part 2](http://www.google.com/codesearch#Wag-gKnV1r8/Alc/ALc.c&q=openal-soft&l=2102).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. You will need to add a line for each new constant, but it should give you an idea about how macros work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define C_TEN 10
#define C_TWENTY 20
#define C_THIRTY 30

#define IFCONST(charstar, define) if(strcmp((charstar), #define) == 0) { \
    return (define); \
}

int getConstValue(const char* constName)
{
    IFCONST(constName, C_TEN);
    IFCONST(constName, C_TWENTY);
    IFCONST(constName, C_THIRTY);

    // No match                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("C_TEN is %d\n", getConstValue("C_TEN"));

    return 0;
}
```

I suggest you run `gcc -E filename.c` to see what gcc does with this code.

Answer (score 6):

C can't do this for you.  You will need to store them in a different structure, or use a preprocessor to build the hundreds of if statements you would need.  Something like [Cogflect](https://github.com/jgarvin/Cogflect) could help.

Answer (score 3):

A C preprocessor macro (that is, something named by a `#define` statement) ceases to exist after preprocessing completes. A program has no knowledge of the names of those macros, nor any way to refer back to them.

If you tell us what task you're trying to perform, we may be able to suggest an alternate approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is what X-Macros are used for:

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/C_preprocessor#X-Macros

But if you need to map a string to a constant, you will have to search for the string in the array of string representations, which is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Where do you get the O(n^2) from? Even if you did a linear search you would only need O(n). Using a std::map reduces this to O(log n).

Comment: @zennehoy OK, it's not `O(n^2)`, it's `O(n*m)`. Comparing strings is `O(n)` not `O(1)`.

Comment: first time i hear of "X-Macros"

Comment: You could use a trie, and then it becomes `O(n)` (where `n` is the length of the string).

Comment: I guess `lex` could generate a very efficient lookup routine (DFA).

Answer (score 1):

There's no such capability built into C.  However, you can use a tool such as [`doxygen`](http://www.doxygen.nl/) to extract all `#define`s from your source code into a data structure that can be read at runtime (doxygen can store all macro definitions to XML).

Comment: in fact the header file i use is generated (from SCADE) and i also have an xml version with the names of constantes.

so i can use python to generate my c code. Thanks

Comment: @azalsup: Instead of generating C code in python, generate a yacc grammar, run yacc (or [GNU Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)) to generate highly optimized C code to do the matching.  Actually the `lex` portion of the tool is probably all you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this with [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/s/gperf/), which generates a lookup function that uses a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

Create a file similar to the following and run gperf with the `-t` option:

```
struct constant { char *name; int value; };
%%
C_CONST_NAME1, 1
C_CONST_NAME2, 2
```

gperf will output C (or C++) code that does the lookup in constant time, returning a pointer to the key/value pair, or NULL.

If you find that your keyword set is too large for gperf, consider using [cmph](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/index.html) instead.